# Newtonsoft.Json Union and Replace simultaneously

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to merge two JSON files and I need to add the objects/sub-objects(nested four or five levels deep), that doesn't exist but overwrite them if they are already there.

So far I got:

```
var target = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
JObject sourceJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
JObject targetJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(target);

if (!JToken.DeepEquals(sourceJObject, targetJObject))
{
    targetJObject.Merge(sourceJObject, new JsonMergeSettings
    { 
        MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
    });

}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetJObject, Formatting.Indented));
```

The problem is that now I get everything that is missing added, but the existing items are skipped. If I use `MergeArrayHandling.Replace` they are replaced, but not added. The question: How can I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do both then?:

```
 targetJObject.Merge(sourceJObject, new JsonMergeSettings
    { 
        MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
    });
 targetJObject.Merge(sourceJObject, new JsonMergeSettings
    { 
        MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Replace
    });
```

Comment: When I try to use it like this there is nothing added at the end for some reason. This was my initial idea as well.

Comment: I just found out that this(the comparison) works only for the main objects and not for the nested ones.

Comment: Ah ok, that is a little unexpected (and undocumented, at least on the Newtonsoft docs).

Comment: Yes, I thought that it is a recursive function that iterates through all of the nested objects, but alas...